# How do I remove a button if a user mouseout(s) of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/5/)

What I have now is almost good, but when you move the mouse along a table row, the button gets removed for some reason, which I don't want. I only what the button to be removed if you mouseout of the whole table.

HTML: Looks like any old table with 3 columns and 12 rows + a `<thead>` with 3 columns.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editData tr').hover(function(){
        $('button').remove();
        $(this).children('td:last-child').append('<button id="editButton">Edit</button>');
    });
    $('#editData').mouseout(function(){
        $('button').remove();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#editData {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #dadce1;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #e1e1e1;
}
#editData tbody {
  border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
  border-top: 0;
}
#editData thead {
  border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-size: 20px;
}
#editData thead th {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#editData th:last-child, #editData tr td:last-child {
  width: 40px;
}
#editData tr {
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
}
#editData td {
  padding: 3px;
}
#editData tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
#editButton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: If the question is about JS/jQuery, why did you add just the CSS to the question?

Comment: I don't know why, sorry, ill fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the second parameter [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). This will attach a `mouseleave` handler to your rows (`tr`).

```
$('#editData tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('td:last-child').append('<button id="editButton">Edit</button>');
}, function() {
    $('button').remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/10/)

Basically, just balanced your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers for the rows.

---

Also if you're interested in knowing the real issue, read about [`mouseout` vs `mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) (demo at bottom of the page).

The problem is, `mouseout` bubbles up so every time it fires in any descendant of the table, it will bubble up to the table element and trigger its mouseout handler.

From the [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) docs:

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves out of the Inner element in this example, a `mouseout` event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger the bound `mouseout` handler at inopportune times. See the discussion for [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) for a useful alternative.

---

`hover` is just a shorthand that attaches `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers, you could explicitly use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout` in your original example and it'd work as well:

```
$('#editData tr').mouseenter(function(){
    $('button').remove();
    $(this).children('td:last-child').append('<button id="editButton">Edit</button>');
});
$('#editData').mouseleave(function(){
    $('button').remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/16/)

This second piece of code is what you asked for: it removes all buttons when you `mouseleave` the table, while the first is my refactored version that appends a button when you `mouseenter` the row and removes it when you `mouseleave` it. Both have the same visible effect.

---

Side-note: I've replaced the `hover` by `mouseenter` in the example as `.hover` would unnecessarily attach the handler to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events when called with a single argument.

With `.hover`, the `mouseleave` for the `tr` would remove the button and create a new one and, when you move the mouse to outside the table, the event would bubble up to the table element removing the just-created button, or if you move the mouse to another row, the handler would also be called twice (`mouseleave` of old row and `mouseenter` of the new hover target row). Of course this is not visible as these handlers would execute in microseconds and browsers may group up repaints. You can see that it is what actually happens with some `console.log`s in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/17/).

This may not make much difference in this use-case (except performance) but in many other cases you may run into issues - many questions on SO are because questioners thought that [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) called with a single argument would attach solely a [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) handler which is not the case.

ps. I aimed this answer at your event bubbling/logic problem, but you don't have to abuse jQuery for something as simple as that. @Daryl Ginn's answer is a very suitable solution for real-world use. `=]`

Answer (score 5):

You're better off appending all of the buttons when the DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
  $('#editData tr td:last-child').append('<button class="editButton">Edit</button>');
});
```

Then use CSS to show/hide the button:

```
.editButton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

#editData tr:hover .editButton {
  display: block;
}
```

Also note the button is now `.editButton`.

---

Here's it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/15/

Comment: You can even strip out JS completely and just add the buttons to your HTML.

Comment: Yes, I usually do not use JS when you can do this with pure CSS. Though the question is still about jQuery and understanding logic behind event bubbling order is helpful for every day use.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace `hover` with `mouseover`, then it works.

Comment: This gives weird blinking on the button when you hover over/near it.

Comment: Hmm... you have better answers to your question then :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the mouseout happens when the mouse leaves the 'td' but the hover wasn't happening again since it was on the 'tr'. By doing the hover on the 'td' instead, you get a new hover starting as you move horizontally with the mouse and cross the column boundary.

Try this change. tr -> td and add a .parent()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editData td').hover(function(){
        $('button').remove();
        $(this).parent().children('td:last-child').append('<button id="editButton">Edit</button>');
    });
    $('#editData').mouseout(function(){
        $('button').remove();
    });
});
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/23b99/13/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#editData tr').hover(function () {
         $('button').remove();
         $(this).children('td:last-child').append('<button id="editButton">Edit</button>');
       }, function () {
         $('button').remove();
       });
    });
```